# Sharepoint Farm - How to change Hostname and Ips of the VM's

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, central-administration, virtual-machine, host-named

I am going to snapshot the virtual machines containing my Sharepoint Farm and put them on a different VM. (When I say snap shot, I'm talking about copying the **entire** virtual machine one at a time - which includes the whole OS and every setting within it; I am **not** performing a reinstall unless I have to.)

The hostname and IP address will have to change because that is provided external.

Where would I find the settings in *SharePoint Central Administration* to configure the IP and hostname of the machines in the farm?

How do the machines in Sharepoint send data between each other? Is it an ODBC connection?

Anything else I need to worry about in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

from this blog ["Move SharePoint Farm VMs with Changing Server Name"](https://sharepointdevblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/move-sharepoint-farm-vms-with-changing-server-name/)
So below are steps, that can be followed to move SharePoint farm on VM with New name and IP.

1. Clone the APP & WFE server and move to new location.
2. Restart APP VM and WFE VM with the NIC Offline
3. Change IP Addresses to the new network
4. Stop All SharePoint Services running on the APP VM and WFE VM
5. Create the Alias on the WFE VM and APP VM Servers
6. Restore the SharePoint Farm related databases to New SQL Server.
   (move all databases
   approach).http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

   - Use the Backup / Restore to the new SQL Server since it sounds like you want to keep the old environment up. Also, it gives you an immediate fail back position
   - If you’re NOT planning on keeping the old environment in place then you don’t need to rename the WFE and APP servers
7. Enable the NICs on APP VM and WFE VM
8. Start the SharePoint Services on APP VM and WFE VM

   1. After your connected and SharePoint is up test connectivity to the New SQL Server ConfigDB by taking the Old SQL Server ConfigDB Offline. If the new environment is still up. You know the SQL Alias is being used
9. Run Rename-SPServer command on both WFE & App server.
   Rename-SPServer needs to be run BEFORE the servername is changed and
   while the Farm is up

   - Manually rename clone machine names for both WFE & APP. For ex., SPS03 & SPS04
   - Rename–SPServer –Identity “WFE11” –Name “WFE1”

Note: you can clone a SQL Server as long as all SQL Services are stopped

Comment: For my reference: NIC = Network Information Center, WFE = Web Front End

Comment: It seems like all I need to know from all of that is `Rename-SPServer -Identity "oldhostname" -Name "newhostname" and run that command after I change the hostname of the windows machine.

Comment: Still +1 because that pointed me in the right direction. Thanks